# Why does using the following macro function in C result in 1 instead of 2?

Tags: c, macros

I have this simple C code with a Macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX(x, y) x>y ? 1 : 0

int main() {
    int i = 9;
    printf("%d\n", MAX(10, i) + 1);
    return 0;
 }
```

Now as I understand the macro function if the value of x (which is 10) is greater than the value of y (which is 9 in this case) then the macro returns 1 other wise zero. So shouldn't the output above be 2 instead of 1 in this case after adding 1 to the final result of the macro?

Comment: Macros aren't functions, and they don't return things. Macros are text substitution (well, token substitution, really). Plug in the actual macro text at the use site, with `10` and `i` textually substituted for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Note that `MAX` is not a good name for this macro, as I would expect it to return either `x` or `y`, whichever is greater. Perhaps `IS_GREATER_THAN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `#define MAX(x, y) x>y ? 1 : 0` to `#define MAX(x, y) (x>y ? 1 : 0)` would fix the problem.

C macro would be replaced directly before entering the compiler, which means the conditional expression becomes `x > y ? 1 : 0 + 1`, both branches will become `1`.

The operator priority makes `+ 1` goes into the conditional expression instead of after it. In this case, parenthesis is required to force the priority.

It's considered a good practice to always add parenthesis to prevent such unexpected behavior in macros. See [C programming book of K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) for complete details.

Comment: But why is this the case?

Comment: @dikshant the designers of C thought that this way was better than the other option

Comment: @M.M For people who play with assembly language, macros are tricks nice to have. But as time passes by and computers become more powerful, macros are becoming less used.

Comment: @NeoX I'm talking about the precedence of `+` vs. the conditional operator  (I assume that is what "dikshant" meant)

Answer (score 4):

`MAX(10, i) + 1` is replaced exactly with `10>i ? 1 : 0 + 1` which gives 1 in either case, due to higher precedence of `+` over `?:`.

As a general rule, put`()` around the replacement *and* around the variables

```
#define MAX(x, y) ((x)>(y) ? 1 : 0)
```

to avoid precedence issues.